# COREUI sidebar minimizer and dropdown is not working

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-5, core-ui

I have to customize sidebar that is provided by COREUI 4.x theme. Below is the code for my sidebar

```
<div class="app-body">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <nav class="sidebar-nav">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a
            class="nav-link"
            routerLink="/dashboard"
            [routerLinkActive]="['active']"
            [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"
          >
            <i class="icon-speedometer"></i> Dashboard
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a
            class="nav-link"
            href="#"
            routerLink="/alerts-configuration"
            [routerLinkActive]="['active']"
            [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"
          >
            <i class="icon-layers"></i> Alert Configuration
          </a>
        </li>
        <li
          class="nav-item nav-dropdown"
          dropdown
          [routerLinkActive]="['active']"
          [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"
        >
          <a class="nav-link nav-dropdown-toggle">
            <i class="icon-puzzle"></i>Administration
          </a>
          <ul class="nav-dropdown-items">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a
                class="nav-link"
                routerLink="/device-management/devices"
                [routerLinkActive]="['active']"
                [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"
              >
                <i class=""></i>Devices Management
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a
                class="nav-link"
                routerLink="/sites"
                [routerLinkActive]="['active']"
                [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"
              >
                <i class="icon-settings"></i>Sites Management
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <button class="sidebar-minimizer brand-minimizer" type="button"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now when I try to click on **Administration**, it wont open the dropdown and also when I try to minimize from the arrow on the bottom, this wont work as well. Please help!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you please provide a full working code example instead of the small snippet?

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue also. I figured out that if the JavaScript files that control sidebar animation are added before the page is generated the sidebar doesn't work.
The solution:
Add the CORE UI JavaScript files at the end.
Looks a little like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
  {the entire html page}
  <script src="https://coreui.io/demo/free/3.4.0/js/main.js" async defer></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

"async defer" may or may not be necessary.

Comment: not working, because your code is for CoreUI 3.x and the question is regarding CoreUI 4.x

Answer (score 1):

With coreui 4.x and BS 5 you should add  `data-coreui="navigation"` to the sidebar-nav element and it will start working correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Please find below my code that is working.

```
 <li class="nav-item nav-dropdown " [appIsAuthorized]="roleconst.ProductAdminAbove" (click)="status=!status"
          [ngClass]="status ? 'open' : ''">
          <a class="nav-link nav-dropdown-toggle ">
            <i class="nav-icon icon-puzzle"></i> Management
          </a>
```

Comment: not working for me. Is your code compatible with CoreUI 4.X?